# SSAS granularies: 2nd cube?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssas, olap-cube, ssas-2008

**Background:**

I'm trying to figure out how to design my SSAS 2012 cube with regard to my user types and reporting interfaces.

My main question is about the best way to handle major logical levels of granularity (which might verge on defining a new business area) within the cube(s) and how those decisions might play out in the reporting layer. I guess I'm also wondering if I'm on the right track in my line of thinking.

**Situation:**

We have two types of users: admins and non-admins. There are two types of Admins: power users and regular users.

I want to offer an SSRS-type solution for the regular users (admins and non-admins) and an Excel-type solution for the power users.

We have two main levels of granularity: PCP and patient.  The PCPKey links the 2 levels of granularity.  That relationship can change.  The company hasn't yet decided what to do about showing data about old PCP/patient relationships.  We may have a company rule, we may allow it to vary from client to client (we already have a non-conforming multi-tenant environment). 
Most analysis will be done on granularity 1.  Admins can see all granularity 1 data; non-admins can only see the data that pertains to them.

Granularity 2 data will need separate detail level reports.  We'll need to drill down to those reports from granularity 1 reports in SSRS, and may eventually need to offer some kind of drill down from granularity 2 to granularity 1 in Excel. Admins will use granularity 2 data & reports infrequently; non-admins will use them often.

**Questions**

My main question is, would it be best to store both granularities in one cube in different Measure Groups, or would it be better to store them in separate cubes and do some kind of linking in SSRS and Excel?  I'm not sure of the difficulties/complexities/performance implications involved.

I should add that PCPs and patients both have M:M relationships with another data element, plus Time, so they are not technically the only levels of granularity we have.  But I figure whatever solution I choose (multiple measure groups or multiple cubes) the lower levels of granularity will fit neatly within.

Or would they?  PCPs have several non-aggregatable measures, which I was planing to deal with using Measure Groups, and you can't nest Measure Groups, can you?  Maybe I'm answering my own question as I write this...? Am I thinking about all of this the wrong way?

Comment: This is multidimensional (not tabular) SSAS, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I would avoid a second cube if at all possible. I think you would find it very inconvenient for combining data in SSRS and limiting when browsing using Excel. Nothing you have said here screams second cube to me. Here's a link on [implementing measure security](http://www.sqljason.com/2010/04/implementing-measure-security-in-ssas.html). Here's [some other good info](http://www.bidn.com/forums/microsoft-business-intelligence/analysis-services/137/restrict-access-to-cube-measure)

Comment: I agree with mmarie. It sounds like 1 cube is the best option for your case.